# React/Redux with Google Sheet API v4 is not fetching data

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, react-redux

I've been making an app that is using the Google Sheet API and React/Redux.

If I hit the API from the component itself it works but I'm having an issue when it comes to fetch data through Redux.

This is code

Action creator:

```
export function fetchList() {
    let data = null;
    gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
        spreadsheetId: FULL_LIST_ID,
        range: RANGE
    }).then((response) => {
        data = response.result.values;
    }, (response) => {
       throw response.result.error.message;
    });

    return {
       type: FETCH_LIST,
       payload: data
   }
}
```

Reducer:

```
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action = {} ) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_LIST:
            return { ...state, list: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
     }
}
```

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchList } from '../../actions/index.jsx';
export class DropdownList extends React.Component { 
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { res: null }
      // this._fetchList = this._fetchList.bind(this);
   }

   componentWillMount() {
      // this should fetch the data from Redux
      this.props.fetchList();
      // so that when 
       console.log(this.props);
      // I should see the values attached to the payload
      // instead this is fetching the data from the API hit here
      this._fetchList();
    }

   // Here I'm hitting the API from the component 
    _fetchList() {
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
           spreadsheetId: FULL_LIST_ID,
           range: ['LIST!A1:B']
        }).then((response) => {
           this.setState({ res: response.result.values });
        }, (response) => {
           throw response.result.error.message;
        });
      }

   _renderList() {
       // this uses the values fetched locally      
       // return this.state.res.map((val, index) => {});
   }

render() {
    if (!this.state.res) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return (
        <div>
                {this._renderList()}
        </div>
    );
   }
}


 function mapStateToProps(state) {
     return { list: state.list }
 }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchList })(DropdownList);
```

Does anybody can help me out? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved!
It was an issue of sync so I needed to use Redux-Thunk as a middleware in my Action Creator.